# How to add mulitple screen on one page? Windows Phone 7 application

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-7

**I am completely novice in Windows phone app development. Till now I have been developing iPhone application. In iphone there is a concept of view and view controller. You can add multiple view on one screen and do hide/show to display multiple screens**.

**I am searching, How can I achieve same things in Windows phone app development.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone applications in general follow the Page based Navigation. If you want to achieve a hide/show multiple views in a single page without Navigating to a new page, you can do that with the help of [UserControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

You can define as many UserControls (==views) as you want and then hide are show them based on your requirements in the YourPage.xaml

And additionally, you would better go with MVVM approach.

check this good example for any further details [Implementing the Model-View-ViewModel Pattern in a Windows Phone Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521153%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your answer, Can you provide me good example for UserControls.

Comment: The above two links contains examples for UserControls. In MVVM approach, UserControls are used as the views. Have a look at them

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I have just one more question, lets say I want to call service api when user select any item from list and want to display loading view, when data comes from api want to hide loading screen and want to display detail view.   which approach should I use for these kind of implementation.

Comment: MVVM is suitable for any kind of application, but as you are new to it and your requirement is very limited..I suggest you using a UserControl for Loading view and the rest of the implementation in the normal xaml page

Answer (score 3):

For a similar pattern, see MVVM:

[How Do I: Use MVVM in a Windows Phone 7 Application?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg241309.aspx)

[Windows Phone Mango: Getting Started with MVVM in 10 Minutes](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Mango-Getting-Started-with-MVVM-in-10-Minutes)

[MVVM in real life Windows Phone applications Part1](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/MVVM-in-real-life-Windows-Phone-applications-Part1)

To hide/show different views/XAML objects/panels, use their name and visibility property, for example:

contentpanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;